# Download file with Javascript and upload to restful web service

Tags: jquery, wcf, rest, upload, download

I'd like to download a PDF file with JQuery/JS and then upload it to a WCF restful web service. Is this possible?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.get(HTML_FILE_URL, function (data) {
                debugger;
                $("#txt").val(data);
            });
        });
```

I have this code which returns something but it doesn't look enough content to be the PDF. It needs to be done with JS on the client as it will be used in Office 365 and I can't post to web services server side.

Comment: Yes you can upload a pdf file to a WCF Rest Service.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below project that uses Jquery to upload files to a server.

[jQuery File Upload Demo](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)

Also find some links that would guide you on how to perform POST/GET to a WCF Rest service via jquery

1. http://blog.uniway.be/accessing-a-wcf-rest-service-through-jquery/

Comment: Can you go into more detail. I need to get a file from a url which will be binary e.g. pdf and upload that file to a restful wcf web service. Trying to avoid using Silverlight. How do I download the file and how do I convert the file with JS/JQuery to a format that the wcf will understand e.g. base64 string?